# Firebase Cloud Messaging export to GBQ shows different totals than Firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

For example, firebase interface shows that  100 000 messages were sent to iOS-app.
But after export in GBQ,  BigQuery shows that 70 000 messages has sdk_platform=iOS and other 30 000 messages has sdk_platform=android.
Maybe someone know why it’s happen?

I expect all messages were sent from one platform

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be better if you can share some screenshots of the notification details and BQ data so others can have a better picture of the scenario. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).